# Check two conditions with a template literal

Tags: javascript, template-literals

I have the following line of code in an object:

```
return {
    subtitle: `Published ${date} by ${author}`
}
```

Here is the thing, it is not necessarily the case that `date` or `author` will be set - which means that I want to conditionally render `subtitle` based on whether `date` is set, `author` is set or both.

Now, if all I had to worry about was date, then I could do the following check:

```
return {
    subtitle: date && `Published ${date}`
}
```

That would work.

Likewise, for author:

```
return {
    subtitle: author && `by ${author}`
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to do a check for BOTH date AND author at the same time.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: `subtitle: [date && \`published ${date}\`, author && \`by ${author}\`].filter(a => a).join(' ')`

Comment: @ChrisG smart solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to do a conditional check like this?

```
return date && author ? { subtitle: `Published ${date} by ${author}` }
    : date && !author ? { subtitle: `Published ${date}` }
    : !date && author ? { subtitle: `by ${author}` }
```

Comment: that definitely works -- but I was wondering if there was a way to do it in a simpler manner

Comment: @ChrisG has a great one it looks like!

Comment: You last ternary expression i.e. `!date && author` is missing the third operand.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `subtitle` can be set to an empty string if both `date` and `author` are empty, then I think there's a case for using a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates):

> A more advanced form of template literals are tagged templates. Tags allow you to parse template literals with a function. The first argument of a tag function contains an array of string values. The remaining arguments are related to the expressions. In the end, your function can return your manipulated string[...]

This would allow the best of both worlds in my opinion. You keep the expressiveness and simplicity of `Published ${date} by ${author}` while abstracting away the gory details of string processing.

It would look like this:

```
subtitle`Published ${date} by ${author}`
//=> 'Published 2019 by John'
//=> or 'Published 2019'
//=> or 'by John'
//=> or ''
```

**Notice:** I have used `flatMap` for the sake of simplicity but this code won't work in IE/Edge unless you polyfill it.

```js
const subtitle = (strings, date, author) =>
  strings
    .flatMap((str, idx) =>
      idx === 0 && date ? [str, date] :
      idx === 1 && author ? [str, author] :
      [])
    .join('')
    .trim();
    
let date;
let author;

date = '2019', author = 'John';
console.log( subtitle`Published ${date} by ${author}` );

date = '2019', author = '';
console.log( subtitle`Published ${date} by ${author}` );

date = '', author = 'John';
console.log( subtitle`Published ${date} by ${author}` );

date = '', author = '';
console.log( subtitle`Published ${date} by ${author}` );
```